# Add custom fields to keycloak user creation

Tags: keycloak

I need to add some additional parameters to the user profile in keycloak, also it should be possible to add when create user via rest and retrieve the details, please help me with an idea about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the 'Custom User Attributes' section in the [Keycloak Developer Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_custom_user_attributes)

All attributes can be retrieved and stored via the REST API. There is a map of `attributes` holding all attributes in the [`UserRepresentation`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation)

Edit:

Keycloak now has a User Profile (currently Technology Preview) for declarative definition of user attributes. For details please see the [Server Administration Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/18.0/server_admin/#user-profile)